# Can I use ReSharper to get automatically format properties with backing fields?

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way that I can configure ReSharper to change the following:

```
    private bool _learnTimerDetailsEditable;
    public bool LearnTimerDetailsEditable { get => _learnTimerDetailsEditable; set => SetProperty(ref _learnTimerDetailsEditable, value); }
```

to make my code look like this:

```
    private bool _learnTimerDetailsEditable;
    public bool LearnTimerDetailsEditable
    {
        get => _learnTimerDetailsEditable;
        set => SetProperty(ref _learnTimerDetailsEditable, value);
    }
```

With format automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Resharper Options, go to:

`Code Editing` / `C#` / `Formatting Style`/ `Line Breaks and Wrapping`.

Find the `Arrangement of declaration blocks` section.

Uncheck `Place abstract/auto property/indexer/event declaration of single line`. If this doesn't work for you, try the next option: `Place simple property/indexer/event declaration on single line`.